# What is the vocative of Gnaeus?

Tags: classical-latin, declension, names, vocative

I would like to know how to decline the name *Gnaeus* in vocative.
I see three options:

- *Gnaee* (regular declension)
- *Gnai* (would make sense by analogy to *Gai* if the name is pronounced /gnaius/)
- *Gnaeus* (if no declined vocative sounds natural, nominative is a reasonable choice)

It is hard to search for the nominative used as vocative, and the same problem comes with the variant *Gnaei* of my second option.
Searching [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/) gives no results for *Gnaee* or *Gnai*.
*Gnaee* sounds weird but I can't figure out if that sounded too weird to the Romans as well.

Is there an attested (preferably classical) vocative of the name *Gnaeus*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I searched for the vocative form *Gnaee* in several *corpora* but did not find any results. A general web search seems to reveal only [automatically generated vocatives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gnaee), which I would not lend much credence to, as well as the excellent 16th century example cited by @JoelDerfner in Juan Luis Vives's [*De Initiis Sectis Et Laudibus Philosophiae*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qp43AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=Gnaee&source=bl&ots=uB42j0sU7E&sig=cWTHofSTKS4pMO5jscLfrbsw7gI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ87KRsM3MAhWLdj4KHTdoAhk4ChDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=Gnaee&f=false). The two alternatives in the critical apparatus (*Gnee* and *Cnee*) correspond to a pretty common transposing of *ae* to *e* (*saeculorum* > *seclorum*) and *g* to *c* (*Gaius* > *Caius*).

To add some more classical weight to this, I looked up similar names ending in *aeus* whose vocative forms are attested in the classical corpus. Here are some examples:

**Hymenaeus**

> turba ruunt et "Hymen" clamant "**Hymenaee!**" frequenter (Ovid, *Heroides* XII)
>
> nec lenius altera virgo
>   aestuat, utque celer venias, **Hymenaee**, precatur. (Ovid, *Metamorphoses*, IX)
>
> [(and many more)](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=hymenaee+site:thelatinlibrary.com)

**Lenaeus**

> Dulce periculum est,
>        o **Lenaee**, sequi deum
>   cingentem viridi tempora pampino. (Horace, *Carmina*, III)
>
> huc, pater o **Lenaee**, ueni, nudataque musto
>   tinge nouo mecum dereptis crura coturnis. (Vergil, *Georgicon*, II)

**Ptolemaeus**

> ne caedes confusa manu permissaque fatis
>   te, **Ptolemaee**, trahat. (Lucan, *Bellum Civile*, X)

All things considered, ***Gnaee* is definitely a safe supposition as the vocative of *Gnaeus***.

Comment: Even though *Gnaee* appears to be absent in extant classical literature, the analogy with the attested vocatives from *-aeus* makes a very strong case. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Eureka, as the scientist said. [J. L. Vives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Luis_Vives), 16th century humanist, uses the vocative of Gnæus Pompeius in *Pompeius Fugiens* ([page 136 of the Brill edition of his early writings, volume I](https://books.google.com/books?id=qp43AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=gnaee&source=bl&ots=uB42j-zV4J&sig=MLFhpkzDtN4Ng_JZJA0Fhxfqg0Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-pOOepc3MAhVGMj4KHaqrCxoQ6AEIjwEwFQ#v=onepage&q=gnaee&f=false)). Brill spells it *Gnæe*, but the notes seem to indicate that one ms spells it *Gnee* and three others spell it *Cnee*.