# Can "ee" appear in Latin?

Tags: morphology, example-request, spelling, vowel, vocative

There are a few instances in Latin where words are spelled with two vowels next to each other, in hiatus: *filii* "sons", *metuunt* "they fear".

Now, the last words of the Emperor Julian II are normally quoted as *vicisti, Galilaee*. The second word here is the vocative of *Galilaeus*, "man from Galilaea".

However, the ending *-ee* looks distinctly *wrong* to my eye. Is this sequence *ee* something found in Classical Latin? Or does it only appear in Later Latin? (Notably, common words like *meus* and *deus* don't take vocatives in *-e*.)

Comment: An easy way to check, which confirms the answers already given: [Packhum search for -ee-](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ee).

Comment: @brianpck That's actually how I got my answer.

Comment: Of course (but I’d argue it wasn’t common) See some examples in my post https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5889/39

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, *Galilaee* sounds right.
See [this question about the vocative of *Gnaeus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/864/79) for details.

There are situations where one finds *-ee-* in Latin without the first *e* belonging to *ae*.
What I found is not word-final, but I assume that is not important for your question.
There are forms of *deesse* and *deerrare*, and if the diphthong *ae* is included, also forms of *praeesse*.
There are lots of examples; you can see the dictionary entries for these words or make [a corpus search](https://latin.packhum.org/search).

In addition, there are first conjugation verbs ending in *-eare*, and in conjunctive it leads to forms like *crees* and *recreetur* (Cicero, *In Q. Caecilium* and *Pro Quinctio*).

It seems that one can legitimately form the Latin wish *beer* ("may I be happy").
I found no attestations of this, but *beet* does exist.

Comment: I joined latin.SE just to express my pleasure with the fact that *beer* means "may I be happy".

Answer (score 12):

The [Vulgata](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch) is full with proper nouns having double *-ee*, specially as endings (e.g. *Bersabee*, *Phacee*, *Osee*). I imagine you are not particularly interested in these. Below are all the other words I could find:

- *deest, deerunt, deessent, deerit, deerant*, etc. E.g.

> [Nm 21:5](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Nm.html#x21_5) locutusque contra Deum et Moysen, ait : Cur eduxisti nos de Ægypto, ut moreremur in solitudine ? **deest** panis, non sunt aquæ : anima nostra jam nauseat super cibo isto levissimo.
>
> [Dt 15:11](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Dt.html#x15_11) Non **deerunt** pauperes in terra habitationis tuæ : idcirco ego præcipio tibi, ut aperias manum fratri tuo egeno et pauperi, qui tecum versatur in terra.

- *eleemosynæ* and related. E.g.

> [Tob 2:22](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Tob.html#x2_22) Ad hæc uxor ejus irata respondit : Manifeste vana facta est spes tua, et **eleemosynæ** tuæ modo apparuerunt. (also in several other verses)

- *reexspecta*. E.g.

> [Is 28:10](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Is.html#x28_10) Quia manda, remanda ; manda, remanda ; exspecta, **reexspecta** ; exspecta, **reexspecta** ; modicum ibi, modicum ibi.

- *procreentur*. E.g.

> [Tob 6:21](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Tob.html#x6_21) Tertia autem nocte, benedictionem consequeris, ut filii ex vobis **procreentur** incolumes.

- *illaqueentur*. E.g.

> [Is 28:13](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Is.html#x28_13) Et erit eis verbum Domini : Manda, remanda ; manda, remanda ; exspecta, reexspecta ; exspecta, reexspecta ; modicum ibi, modicum ibi ; ut vadant, et cadant retrorsum, et conterantur, et **illaqueentur**, et capiantur.

- *spontanee*. E.g.

> [Os 14:5](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Os.html#x14_5) Sanabo contritiones eorum ; diligam eos **spontanee** : quia aversus est furor meus ab eis.

Some of the above have other declensions that are not in the Vulgata, but also have double *ee*. For instance, subjunctive passive declensions of *[procreo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/procreo#Latin)*.

Regarding the period, some seem to be Classical (e.g. *procreo*), with others being Late Latin (e.g. *eleemosynæ*).

Comment: "I imagine you are not particularly interested in these." - but their specific example is for the ending -ee.

Comment: @OrangeDog Maybe I got the emphasis of the question wrong. Let's see what Draconis says.

Comment: @luchonacho No, you're right; I'm more interested in native Classical Latin words, and proper names in the Vulgate are generally transcriptions from Greek and Hebrew.

Answer (score 8):

Rarely *ee* can be used as [geminatio vocalium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geminatio_vocalium), i.e. to denote that the *e* is pronounced long. This was mainly used in Oscan and sometimes borrowed to Latin.

For example l*ee*ge in [this inscription](http://db.edcs.eu/epigr/epi_einzel.php?s_sprache=en&p_belegstelle=CIL%2001,%2001439):
 *Vediovei patrei / genteiles Iuliei // Vedi[ov]ei aara // Leege Albana dicata*
(*aa*ra also denotes long a).

M. Loporcaro in Vowel Length from Latin to Romance notes that Accius (c. 170-90 BC) recommended to write long vowels by double letters. F. Rovai (in the context of grave inscriptions) mentiones that this practice was chiefly restricted to either official epigraphy or poetic, archaising epitaphs.

Comment: Very interesting. You wouldn't happen to have an example (preferably with your comments)?

Comment: I do not know it very well, I happened to meet it today by an accident in the context of Greek inscriptions of Latin names but I will find something.

Comment: @VladimirF This is very interesting! If I understand right, that inscription is from circa 100 BC?

Comment: The site states -150 to -76.

Comment: More examples https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5889/39